# ABP tries setting Outdated setting value from DB and fails

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-core-3.1, application-settings

I NuGet updated ABP from 5.6.0 to 5.9.0.

On startup, I get the error ***There is no setting defined with name: XYXY.XXYXY***

I know this Setting was used about a year ago and has been removed since then from the AppSettingProvider.GetSettingDefinitions().
As I can see, the value is still in the database.
ABP5.6.0 just did not try to set the setting form the db because it was not defined in the SettingProvider. I think thats the correct behaviour

Is there a way to prevent this error? (other than manually cleanse the db from outdated entries or re-introduce obsolete settingdefinitions to SettingProvider)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, ABP has solved the issue in Version 5.10

See Pull-request:
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/5643

Thanks maliming (GitHub) for the fix

Thanks aaron for the answer.